# How to design tringle border in css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[image]
Using Html5, css3, Bootstrap I want to design this div like this

I am very new to css. so Please help me to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Check this snippet

```css
.box {
    width:300px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    height:100px;
    top:50px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified @Hitesh Misro's answer according to your updated requirement.

```css
.box {
    width:300px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    height:100px;
    top:50px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}

.box span
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  top:25px;
  text-align:center;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Hello this is some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using html5 and css3.

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 2px solid #c2e1f5;
 top:20px;
 width:400px;
    }
    .arrow_box p{margin:10px; padding:10px;}
    .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
    }

    .arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-left: -30px;
    }
    .arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 33px;
 margin-left: -33px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
  <p>  Text Area</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.boxDiv {
     position: relative;
     background: #ffffff;
     border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
        top: 50px;
        min-height:100px;
    }
    .boxDiv:after, .boxDiv:before {
     bottom: 100%;
     left: 50%;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: " ";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
    }
    .boxDiv:after {
     border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
     border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
     border-width: 30px;
     margin-left: -30px;
    }
    .boxDiv:before {
     border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
     border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
     border-width: 36px;
     margin-left: -36px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="boxDiv">Contents</div>
```